# How to use default Rating component?

Tags: aem

For some e-commerce project, I would like to give the online shop customers the possibility to rate the merchant products (something like product rating in amazon). I have found out, that there is a AEM6 Default Rating Component. Can somebody give me a guidance how to use the Default Rating Component?

Answer (score -1):

When you double click on the placed Rating component, an edit dialog opens up.

You can configure the Rating component to either  allow users to submit a rating or show the average results of ratings already submitted.

[image: rating dialog]

Select the Display Only option. If checked, **the Rating component will only display the average ratings submitted for the page**. If unchecked, it will allow users to submit ratings for the page by clicking on the stars.  Default is unchecked.

To can see the full guide about the rating component [here](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/author/social-communities/using-ratings.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Please include the essential parts of the answer rather than simply a link to where an answer may be found.